# Mechanical Turk - Cannot see my published Batch in the Worker sandbox

Tags: sandbox, mechanicalturk, mturk

I'm trying to publish a new Image Classification batch, but the task is not published.

I've created a [presentation](https://github.com/yonatanbitton/vasr_mturk_examples/blob/main/mTurk_steps.pdf) describing the full steps I'm doing on mTurk and the problem.

[image: published_batch]
I didn't ask for any qualification for the workers (Screenshot attached).
[image: quals]

Yet, I don't see the task in the worker sandbox: https://workersandbox.mturk.com/projects
I'm searching by my name: "huji nlp lab" and the title "Visual Analogies"

I think that the problem is the "0% published"? I did publish my batch, and pressed "Publish" (screenshot attached).
[image: 0% published]
[image: publish]

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question. Contact the support for the service you're using, that's probably a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that the images should be hosted in S3 bucket (not github, nor imgur, just S3), with public access and adding CORS permissions.
Then it will work with the default layout and the batch will be shown as "published".